# Update query in JPA using composite primary key

Tags: jpa, entitymanager, composite-primary-key

I have an entity Student with a composite primary key (indId, studentId). I want to update some rows in this table. My codes:

```
private EntityManager em = null;

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityMgr(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}

public void updateStudent(Student student){
    em.merge(student);
}
```

When this code runs, an insert query is performed (and accordingly since its an insert, an exception is thrown if the primary key already exists). I am not sure how to write an update query (using JPA) when using a composite primary key. Looking for suggestions. Thanks.

**Edit**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {
    private Integer studentId;
    private Long indId;
    private Integer field1; 
    private Integer field2;

@Id
@Column(name="student_id")
public Integer getStudentId() {
    return student;
}

@Id
@Column(name="ind_id")
public Long getIndId() {
    return indId;
}

//rest of the getters and setters
}


public class StudentBean{
 // properties 

    public void update(){
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setIndId(this.getIndId());
    student.setStudentId(this.getStudentId());
    .
    .

    // have a service class which I did not include
    studentDao.updateStudent(student)
   }

   // getters and setters

}

@Repository("StudentDao")
public class StudentDao{
    private EntityManager em = null;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityMgr(EntityManager em) {
         this.em = em;
    }

    public void updateStudent(Student student){
          em.merge(student);
    }
 }


Stacktrace (where indId = 117 and studentId = 1)

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:   Duplicate entry '117-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2006)
... 98 more
```

Comment: Show us the code and mapping of your entity. Tell us what it contains. Show us the full stack trace of the exception and the SQL queries being executed.

Comment: Please see the edited part and let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `Student` entity really does have a primary key made up of 2 coulmns, then you should be using the `@EmbeddedId` annotation and using an `@Embeddable` class to hold the 2 fields in the Primary Key.